# Same code in python3.6 produces larger file than python2.7. Bin to ASCII conversion

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, text, ascii

Can somebody help me understand why when run under Python2 the file created by this code is much smaller (and the expected file size) than in Python3?

```py
binary_str="00110111011010110101......"

num_bytes = int(len(binary_str)/8)

with open('output', 'w') as f:
    output_str = ""
    for i in range(num_bytes):
        output_str += chr(int(binary_str[i:i+8],2))
    f.write(output_str)
    f.close()
```

binary_str is a 1330byte long string. In Python2.7 this code produces a 1330byte file containing the relevant ascii data. When run with python3.6 balloons up in size to 1974bytes. Why this difference in behaviour?

Comment: inside a with statement, closing the resource isn't necessary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably produce other characters than defined in 7-bit ascii. Since python 3.x conforms to unicode, encoding of characters outside of the 7-bit ascii code table are encoded using multiple bytes.

The most famous unicode character encoding technique is [utf-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8). It is wide spread. In this standard one character could have been encoded by using up to 4 bytes.

So it's not a surprise when your file grows up under the use of python 3.x

It is even very likely, that you get other content beside different file size with python 3.x compared to python 2.x

To be really sure, what I write here, it would be best if you post your complete original bit string to convert. So I will have to verify it.

Btw. python 2.x support is abandoned since the early beginning of this year 2020. [See sunsetting...](https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/)

Comment: Opening the file not in binary mode is a problem too.  I'm quite surprised it generated the correct output in Python 2.7.

Comment: fine, my pleasure